# Deploying a Spring application with Tomcat gradle plugin

Tags: spring, tomcat, gradle, web-applications, deployment

I´m trying to deploy a spring application on tomcat using the bmuschko tomcat plugin (https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin).

I have an index.jsp in my webapp folder that is shown correctly. The thing is that my application is not being deployed. (but Tomcat is working fine as my index.jsp is displayed correctly). I think it might be related to the fact that it is a spring application but I have no clue how to overcome this (I don´t get any error and I´m not sure where I can find my catalina log).

My class build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.3.3.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-jpa'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'tutorialDatabaseServer.Application'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { 
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testCompile("junit:junit")

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    //    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.3.3")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb")
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-validator', version:'4.2.0.Final'
    compile group: 'javax.el', name: 'el-api', version: '2.2.1-b04'
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4.1212'

    def tomcatVersion = '8.5.16'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
        "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.5.2",
        "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"

}

tomcat {
    httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
    ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
}


task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.3'
}

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.3'
    }
}
```

and my application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

private static final Logger log = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
}
}
```

Many thanks.

EDIT: after changing my application class as suggested, the tomcat log is the following one:

```
jul 25, 2017 8:53:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio2-8080"]
jul 25, 2017 8:53:37 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio2-8009"]
jul 25, 2017 8:53:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting service [Tomcat]
jul 25, 2017 8:53:37 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
jul 25, 2017 8:53:37 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFORMACIÓN: No global web.xml found
jul 25, 2017 8:54:08 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMACIÓN: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 25, 2017 8:54:09 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMACIÓN: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 25, 2017 8:54:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@1f014eaa]
jul 25, 2017 8:54:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio2-8080"]
jul 25, 2017 8:54:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio2-8009"]
jul 25, 2017 8:55:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio2-8080"]
jul 25, 2017 8:55:31 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio2-8009"]
jul 25, 2017 8:55:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting service [Tomcat]
jul 25, 2017 8:55:31 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
jul 25, 2017 8:55:31 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig getDefaultWebXmlFragment
INFORMACIÓN: No global web.xml found
jul 25, 2017 8:56:02 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMACIÓN: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 25, 2017 8:56:03 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMACIÓN: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
jul 25, 2017 8:56:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMACIÓN: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@4988a907, tutorialDatabaseServer.Application@754b42bf]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend SpringBootServletInitializer and override configure() method to deploy it as a war file, please see [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

Edit:

Your build.gradle includes incompatible logging dependencies. On startup, classloader fails to load slf4j classes and exits with java.lang.StackOverflowError. To solve it I had to modify build.gradle like below.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.4.RELEASE")
        classpath 'com.bmuschko:gradle-tomcat-plugin:2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-jpa'
    version =  '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'tutorialDatabaseServer.Application'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases"
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile('ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3')
    compile('org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.25')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator") {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind")
    compile("org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.3.3")
    compile('javax.el:el-api:2.2.1-b04')
    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1212')

    testCompile("junit:junit")

    def tomcatVersion = '8.5.15'
    tomcat "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:${tomcatVersion}",
           "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-juli:8.5.2",
           "org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:${tomcatVersion}"
    }

    tomcat {
        httpProtocol = 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol'
        ajpProtocol  = 'org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNio2Protocol'
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.3'
    }
```

Comment: now I get the error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':tomcatRun'.
> java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. @taner

Comment: Can you set outputFile of plugin to see what is printed in tomcat logs.

Comment: I have added the tomcat log @taner . Thanks again

Comment: Hi, there is an incompatibility in dependencies. This is why it fails. Edited my reply with a working build.gradle file. It is loading spring boot application on gradle 3.5.1. I hope it works for you.